# Gradient of the distance of point and set

Tags: calculus, derivatives, metric-spaces

Let $A⊂\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed subset and $d:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ 
 defined by $d(x)=\inf\{||x-y|| | y\in A\}$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}^n$) where $||v||$ is the Euclid norm of $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.If $d$ is totally differentiable at $x_{0}\notin A$,prove that $||(\mathrm{grad} \ d)(x_{0})|| = 1$.

If $A$ is the one point,It is obvious.However I have no idea in the case $A$ is merely closed subset. It comes down to the one point case ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/338473/78539.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, $|d(x)-d(y)|\le \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$. This yields an upper bound, $\|\nabla d(x)\|\le 1$.

To show the lower bound, it suffices to exhibit a direction $u$ (a unit vector) such that the rate of change of $d$ in that direction is $\pm 1$. What direction should that be? Moving toward the nearest point of $A$ should do the job, with the rate of change being $-1$.

The nearest point indeed exists. For a fixed $x\notin A$, consider the compact set $$A'=A\cap \{y\colon \|x-y\|\le 2d(x)\}.$$ Note that the function $y\mapsto \|x-y\|$ attains a minimum at some $y^*\in A'$, and that this minimum is also its minimum on $A$.

The derivative of $d$ in the direction $u=(y^*-x)/\|y^*-x\|$ is $-1$ since the distance to $y^*$ decreases at that rate.